# Raspberry PI 4 HDMI Touch screen

Tags: display, touchscreen

I have been using my Raspberry Pi for a while. In the beginning, I had some issues setting up the config.txt with the correct settings while I make it run on my TV. I decided to order a touch screen for it and it arrived a few days ago. Since then, I have no luck in catching the right setting for it to make it work. It says: "No signal" or just black screen.

The touchscreen: 7Inch TFT LCD Display jrp7007 Touch Screen Monitor 1024x600

I have used the following settings:

```
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
config_hdmi_boost=10
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
```

I also have tried safe mode.
However, still no progress.

This is the current config.txt I am using:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
disable_overscan=0

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=16

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
config_hdmi_boost=9

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
#hdmi_enable_4kp60=1

max_usb_current=1

hdmi_force_hotplug=1

config_hdmi_boost=10

hdmi_group=2

hdmi_mode=87

hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
```

Comment: If you don't get any answers on here in a reasonable time, you could try the official Raspberry Pi Forum. They have lots of questions about HDMI and LCD screens. If none of the existing ones help, you can join the forum and ask a new question, probably best in the 'Troubleshooting' section. Here is the address https://forums.raspberrypi.com/index.php

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Raspberry Pi OS (64-bit)